# ssh to an IP without any local ssh multiplexing/control master

Tags: ssh, ssh-multiplexing

I have configured my ssh (on Linux) to use SSH multiplexing & control master. It's great and speeds things up.

But now I want to test a load balancer. How can I ssh to an IP address and *not* use any ssh multiplexing / control master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions given the level of detail in the question.

I assume what you've setup essentially boils down to:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ...
```

If you want to disable multiplexing you simply need to set `ControlMaster` to `no` (or comment it since `no` is the default.

If you only want to disable it for a single connection, the manual has you covered:

> -o option
>
> Can be used to give options in the format used in the configuration file. This is useful for specifying options for which there is no separate command-line flag.

Reading a little further would even yield:

> -S ctl_path
>
> Specifies the location of a control socket for connection sharing, or the string “none” to disable connection sharing.

Any of these three should let you disable multiplexing with more or less granularity depending on which you choose.